# Mathjax - vector symbol not loading in chrome

Tags: math, latex, mathjax

I'm having an issue in display of vector symbols in Chrome. Its displayed as small boxes instead of the vector symbol. How can I solve it?

[image]
Following is the latex code for that.

```
If \(\vec{a}=2\vec{i}-7\vec{j}+\vec{k}\) and \(\vec{b}=\vec{i}+3\vec{j}-5\vec{k}\) and \(\vec{a}.m\vec{b}=120\), then the value of m is equal to:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome on Windows has problems accessing a few of the characters in the MathJax fonts (see [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/the-vec-command-appears-broken-in-windows-xp) for details).  The over arrow is one of them.  Historically, Chrome has had trouble with various individual characters for no reason that I could determine, and different ones for different versions of Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but for anyone still searching for a way to display a vector using MathJax in chrome on windows `\overrightarrow{a}` renders correctly and does the job...

Answer (score 0):

(vector f = m x vector a)

```
<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
 <mover>
  <mi>f</mi>
  <mo>&rarr;</mo>
 </mover>
 <mo>=</mo>
 <mi>m</mi>
 <mi>&times;</mi>
 <mover>
  <mi>a</mi>
  <mo>&rarr;</mo>
 </mover>
</math>
```